# Magento 2: Add success message with Identifier

Tags: magento2.2, success-message

In Magento Message Collection 
 [/vendor/magento/framework/Message/Collection.php](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Message/Collection.php).

There are two method to get and delete message by Identifier, `getMessageByIdentifier` and  `deleteMessageByIdentifier`. But I didn't get any way to set message with identifier, Does anyone knows how to set identifier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular class `/vendor/magento/framework/Message/Collection.php` there is a `addMessage` method that looks like

```
    /**
     * Adding new message to collection
     *
     * @param MessageInterface $message
     * @return $this
     */
    public function addMessage(MessageInterface $message)
    {
        if (!isset($this->messages[$message->getType()])) {
            $this->messages[$message->getType()] = [];
        }
        // Prevent adding duplicate messages.
        $foundIndex = array_search($message, $this->messages[$message->getType()], false);
        if (false === $foundIndex) {
            $this->messages[$message->getType()][] = $message;
            $this->lastAddedMessage = $message;
        } else {
            $this->lastAddedMessage = $this->messages[$message->getType()]    [$foundIndex];
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

You see, this method accepts `@param MessageInterface $message`.

If you open `/vendor/magento/framework/Message/MessageInterface.php` you will notice that there is `setIdentifier` mandated

```
    /**
     * Setter message identifier
     *
     * @param string $identifier
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setIdentifier($identifier);
```

So, the way to set an identifier is to do it on an object of type `Magento\Framework\Message\MessageInterface`, or to be even more accurate, of type `Magento\Framework\Message\AbstractMessage` because this abstract class actually `implements MessageInterface`.

Anyway, suppose you have injected a MenagerInterface in your class like

```
    /*
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager
    ) {
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
    }
```

you should be able to write something like this in a method of yours in the same class

```
   $messages = $this->messageManager->getMessages();
   $message = $messages->getLastAddedMessage();
   if ($message) {       
        $message->setIdentifier('YOUR_ID_HERE')->setIsSticky(true);   
   }
```

//EDIT

Please notice that `$this->messageManager->getMessages()` returns s Collection of messages, the one that you have mentioned `Magento\Framework\Message\Collection`, so if you need any other than the last message, you can just simply filter this collection, or loop through it to get the message you need and then you simply call `setIdentifier` on that message.

I hope this helps.